# Does java stream create some temporary list while creating Immutable List?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, immutability

As no element can be added to an immutable list, I think java stream first collects the elements into a list and then creates a new immutable list with the elements from the first list. So, there are two instances of the list and the first instance becomes available for garbage collection.

So, my question is

1. whether stream actually creates two list objects as mentioned above?
2. if not, how does stream create a immutable list?

Comment: What specific code are you using to create an immutable list from a stream?

Comment: I am not using any particular code.. Just trying to understand how streams create immutable Collections (here I mentioned List to give a more specific case).. whether they first create a copy and then return an immutable instance? I am aware of Guava's ImmutableList.toImmutableList(), Java's collectingAndThen(toList(), ImmutableList::copyOf) and so on and I think they create a copy first.

Comment: What makes you think streams are creating immutable Collections? Your question seems to be based on an assertion I don't see any foundation for, e.g. [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) doesn't say it creates an immutable List.

Comment: Streams don't create immutable Collections.. My question is when I want to collect my element to an immutable list (instead of normal mutable Java list like ArrayList or LinkedList), how does stream put the elements to the immutable list as add/remove is not supported to immutable list? The only way I see is first collect all the possible elements to a temporary list and then create immutable list using the temporary list.. Is my assumption true?

Comment: Why do you assume that creating an immutable list using a temporary list requires a copy?

Comment: It looks like your question requires clarification as it is different than one you described in *your* second comment. Also if you are asking *how* to create immutable lists via stream you can use construct like `stream.collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), Collections::unmodifiableList));`. As Louis mentioned (maybe not explicitly, but I think that was intention) `Collections.unmodifiableList(list)` doesn't require copying any elements from `list`, it simply creates *wrapper* list class which will handle all methods in a way appropriate to immutable class.

Comment: I think I have mentioned in my previous comment and my question, how I think stream would be collecting to an Immutable list ( when we want to output to be immputable list). Also, mentioned if it's not the way I mentioned, can someone explain how does it work when someone wants to collect elements into immutable list ( part 2 of my question)

Comment: IMO your question is unclear. For question: "how does stream create a immutable list?" answer could be: it doesn't by itself, it just execute steps chosen by programmer. It is like asking "how iterator collects elements?" - it doesn't, its job is to iterate over elements, how those elements will be used is up to programmer.

Comment: You're asking how Java streams create immutable lists. **It doesn't**. If you want a list with different characteristics (such as immutable) than the default list provided by the stream implementation code, then *you* supply the code for that. So it seems like you're *really* asking: *How would I go about doing that?* Is that your question? If so, please **edit** the question and clarify it.

Answer (score 4):

Any implementation is going to be accumulating elements somehow, into a structure that has some level of mutability, and then returning a list that cannot be modified.

The details of how that is done are up to the implementation, but here are several possibilities:

- The elements are accumulated into an `ArrayList`, which is then copied to an immutable list.
- The elements are accumulated into an `ArrayList`, and a wrapper preventing modification is returned (such as `Collections.unmodifiableList`.)  Since no other objects have references to the original `ArrayList`, the result is as immutable as it gets.
- The elements are accumulated into some structure that isn't technically a list, such as a raw array, and that array is copied or wrapped in an immutable list object.

The choice of which of these implementations depends on the particular `Collector` you call, such as `Collectors.toList()` or `ImmutableList.toImmutableList()`.  The details of that implementation are up to the authors of that library, who can use any of these strategies.

Comment: From the API doc for `Collectors.toList()`: "There are no guarantees on the type, *mutability*, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned." As it stands, the question is too broad to answer well.

Comment: @AndyThomas and there is `Collectors::toUnmodifiableList` since 11 too

Answer (score 2):

Considering the following example:

```
List<String> people
         = getPeople().stream()
                      .collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), Collections::unmodifiableList));
```

For this example I am using the `Collections::unmodifiableList` method, so let's check the source code:

```
/**
 * Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list.  This method allows
 * modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal
 * lists.  Query operations on the returned list "read through" to the
 * specified list, and attempts to modify the returned list, whether
 * direct or via its iterator, result in an
 * <tt>UnsupportedOperationException</tt>.<p>
 *
 * The returned list will be serializable if the specified list
 * is serializable. Similarly, the returned list will implement
 * {@link RandomAccess} if the specified list does.
 *
 * @param  list the list for which an unmodifiable view is to be returned.
 * @return an unmodifiable view of the specified list.
 */
public static <T> List<T> unmodifiableList(List<? extends T> list) {
    return (list instanceof RandomAccess ?
            new UnmodifiableRandomAccessList<>(list) :
            new UnmodifiableList<>(list));
}
```

As mentioned in the comments by @Pshemo, the `UnmodifiableList` works as a *wrapper* for your list, you can also check in the source code that this class contains a list inside:

```
 static class UnmodifiableList<E> extends UnmodifiableCollection<E>
                               implements List<E> {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = -283967356065247728L;
     final List<? extends E> list; // Here is the wrapped list

     UnmodifiableList(List<? extends E> list) {
         super(list);
         this.list = list;
     }
    ...
}
```

The source code used to extract these codes can be [found here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html).

So answering your question:

- The stream creates the immutable list using methods like `Collections::unmodifiableList` method
- Internally streams do not add anything in a different list, since the `ImmutableList` just work as a wrapper to the `Collection`

You can also check in the docs and sources to understand how exaclty those immutable related methods and objects work.